# How to restart flask server via API while it uses multiprocessing inside

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, waitress, pebble

I have a flask app with waitress that gets some data in post-request, then it runs some long computations  in `long_function` and returns result. These computations are parallel and I'm using `pebble` because I need a timeout option. Also I want the user to be able to send a request to restart the server (i.e. he want to change the number of threads for `waitress`)

I've found this solution https://gist.github.com/naushadzaman/b65534d912f1551c7d8366b326b7a151
It mostly works, but it doesn't interact well with my `pebble` pool. I'm having trouble reloading the server while it is in the pool. If I use `long_function_without_pool`, that doesn't use any multiprocessing, I can reload server even if it is currently does some job (results are lost, of course, but this is what I want). But with `long_function` I have to wait for the pool to be closed and only then can I restart the server. If I try to send restart request while the pool is still open, I get an error:

`OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

So I suppose that `p.terminate()` doesn't work if there is a `Pool` running.

How can I fix this code, or maybe should I use a different solution?

Brief instructions on how to replicate this error:

1. start the app
2. send POST-request with empty body to http://localhost:5221/
3. before you get a response (you'll have 5 seconds) send GET-request without variables to http://localhost:5221/restart/
4. enjoy. Server is stuck now and is not responding to anything

   ```
   import subprocess
   from flask import Flask
   from flask_restful import Api, Resource
   from flask_cors import CORS
   from webargs.flaskparser import parser, abort
   import json
   import time
   import sys
   from waitress import serve
   from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
   from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
   from pebble import ProcessPool, ProcessExpired
   import functools

   some_queue = None


   APP = Flask(__name__)
   API = Api(APP)
   CORS(APP)

   @APP.route('/restart/', methods=['GET'], endpoint='start_flaskapp')
   def restart():
       try:
           some_queue.put("something")
           print("Restarted successfully")
           return("Quit")
       except:
           print("Failed in restart")
           return "Failed"

   def start_flaskapp(queue):
       global some_queue
       some_queue = queue
       API.add_resource(FractionsResource, "/")
       serve(APP, host='0.0.0.0', port=5221, threads=2)

   def long_function():
       with ProcessPool(5) as pool:
           data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
           future = pool.map(functools.partial(add_const, const=1), data, timeout=5)
           iterator = future.result()
           result=[]
           while True:
               try:
                   result.append(next(iterator))
               except StopIteration:
                   break
               except TimeoutError as error:
                   print("function took longer than %d seconds" % error.args[1])
       return(result)

   def long_function_without_pool():
       data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
       result = list(map(functools.partial(add_const, const=1), data))
       return(result)

   def add_const(number, const=0):
       time.sleep(5)
       return number+const

   class FractionsResource(Resource):
       @APP.route('/', methods=['POST'])
       def post():
           response = long_function()
           return(json.dumps(response))

   if __name__ == "__main__":

       q = Queue()
       p = Process(target=start_flaskapp, args=(q,))
       p.start()
       while True: #wathing queue, if there is no call than sleep, otherwise break
           if q.empty():
               time.sleep(1)
           else:
               break
       p.terminate() #terminate flaskapp and then restart the app on subprocess
       args = [sys.executable] + [sys.argv[0]]
       subprocess.call(args)
   ```